# PHP Fatal error: Out of memory?! (Sth. different than on other topics)

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, memory, out-of-memory

I know there are a lot of “PHP Fatal error: Out of memory” topics out there.
Till now I tried everything I found on those, but still I get the message.

**My setup:**

```
Windows Server 2008R2 Standard (64Bit; running on a VM)
6GB RAM
IIS 7.5
PHP 5.4
```

**php.ini:**

```
memory_limit = 4000M
```

**.php-file:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','4000M');
flush();
ob_flush();
```

What I’m doing is running a query on the MSSQL server which gives me back a very large set of data. It seems to be a little more than 2GB.

What I see on the server (Task Manager: Memory), when I load the webpage:
From +-2GB it climbs to +-3.7GB and then drops back to +-2GB.

**EDIT:**
The webpage shows me no results and I get the “PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1836580864) (tried to allocate 18350074 bytes) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ELogMonitor\php\helpers\fncs.php on *line 76*” error on the PHP54_error.log.

BTW: If I run the query on the SQL Server Management Studio, no problem occurs.

The query (For those interested in what I'm doing.):

```
$sql = "SELECT dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
        ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
        ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
        ,dbo.Sources.Source
        ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
        ,dbo.Main.Time
        ,dbo.Main.Msg
    FROM dbo.EntryTypes
    INNER JOIN dbo.Main ON dbo.EntryTypes.pk_EntryType = dbo.Main.fk_EntryType
    INNER JOIN dbo.EventIds ON dbo.EventIds.pk_EventId = dbo.Main.fk_EventId
    INNER JOIN dbo.LogNames ON dbo.LogNames.pk_LogName = dbo.Main.fk_LogName
    INNER JOIN dbo.Servers ON dbo.Servers.pk_Server = dbo.Main.fk_Server
    INNER JOIN dbo.Sources ON dbo.Sources.pk_Source = dbo.Main.fk_Source
    WHERE dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType = 'Error'
    GROUP BY dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
        ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
        ,dbo.Sources.Source
        ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
        ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
        ,dbo.Main.Msg
        ,dbo.Main.Time
    ORDER BY dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
        ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
        ,dbo.Sources.Source
        ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
        ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
        ,dbo.Main.Msg
        ,dbo.Main.Time";
```

What I'm doing with the result:

```
function tableizeQryRes($arr) {
  $isFirst=true;
  $tbl = '<table>';
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($isFirst) {
      $tblHeader = '<tr><td></td>';
      $tblBody = '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
      foreach ($val as $sub_key => $sub_val) {
        $tblHeader .= '<td>'.$sub_key.'</td>';
        $tblBody .= '<td>'.$sub_val.'</td>';
      }
      $tblHeader .= '</tr>';
      $tblBody .= '</tr>';
      $tbl .= $tblHeader;
      $tbl .= $tblBody;
      $isFirst=false;
    } else {
      $tbl .= '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
      foreach ($val as $sub_key => $sub_val) {
        $tbl .= '<td>'.$sub_val.'</td>';         //(<-- line 76)
      }
      $tbl .= '</tr>';
    }
  }
  $tbl .= '</table>';

  echo '<div>';
  echo $tbl;
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Given the nature of your requirements to collect so much data, you would be better off handling it in smaller chunks.  Can you distribute the workload?  Setting range of rows per chunk.

Comment: I could divide it in 2 or more queries but then I will take much more time than it already does. So that would not be a good idea.
Somehow it should be possible to fix this problem I thing, but till now I haven’t figured out how to fix it. If I run the query on the SQL Server Management Studio, no problem occurs.

Comment: If it takes twice as long to execute by being divided, that's surely better than never running because it exceeds memory

Comment: But you've not shown any code, or even pseudo code logic - are you trying to load an entire resultset into memory? Or are you processing that dataset one row at a time?

Comment: Added some detail now.

Comment: So you're reading the entire resultset into an array, and then looping through that array to generate your output? Don't, pass the resultset resource to the `tableizeQryRes()` function, and loop through a row at a time there, so no need to have a 4GB+ array in PHP memory

Comment: Yes. Actually I think now what the problem is, the $tbl gets to big to handle. I now changed the code that every loop the tbl gets echoed instead of storing all inside that string. Now firefox crashed... xD I think I have to write it out on several pages. ;) (Btw., fetching the data into the array does work, so the problem hasn't to do with that.)

Comment: Building a giant $tbl string may simply be the straw that broke the camels back; creating a giant array from your resultset is also hogging large amounts or memory; best solution would be to eliminate both memory hogs

Comment: People are usually happy to scroll through a large amount of data (less clicks).  Pagination is most useful at mitigating the performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity , what type of query are you running and why is the return so large ?

If you working with multiple result sets, why dont you try calling the query in pieces by limiting the results. basically taking smaller chunks out at a time.

Then after each query do what needs to be done and clear the data with : 
flush();
ob_flush();

But i need to actually know how you calling it and what you are actually calling . 
A page, A web service call, Console app ??

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Added some detail now.